# Can not get image from file

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I have cache images in file like so:

[image]

I want to get these images, I have tried like this:

```
let documentsURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
let imagePath = documentsURL.absoluteString.stringByAppendingString("1.png")
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imagePath)
print(image)
```

the imagePath give me:

> "file:///Users/entropy/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3A41D467-B991-4F85-93CD-10C227ED4F69/data/Containers/Data/Application/F5005FAA-7107-41DD-86D2-38C302742063/Documents/1.png"

You see it gives me exactly the image path, but when I `print(image)`, the image is `nil`.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
**EDIT**

```
let path = "~/1.png"
let expandedPath = path.stringByExpandingTildeInPath
let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: expandedPath)!)

let image = UIImage(data: data!)
print(image)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `let imageData: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfFile: expandedPath)` should be `let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: imagePath)!)`